# Send emails from SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, email, database-mail

I would like to send emails from SQL Server 2008.

Here is my code:

```
USE mydatabase

declare @keywords nvarchar(3000)  
Select @keywords = null

SELECT 
    @Keywords = Coalesce(@Keywords + '; ', '') + Email 
from 
    SharedDataUser

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
    @profile_name = 'MyTestProfile', 
    @recipients=@keywords,
    @subject = 'Test mail'
```

I am able to send email by database mail.

**Issue**

I am sending mail to multiple users. Each user has different due date and I need to send that due date with email body. I didn't find the way. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have an actual question, or just a requirement and want us to do your job? Do we get paid?

Comment: hi @RemusRusanu sorry for that actually i am new here. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to have a different body for each recipient using this approach.  You could use a cursor to iterate over the recipients, calling sp_send_dbmail for each recipient.  You can then set the @body parameter to whatever is appropriate for that recipient i.e. their due date.